# Words in German that begin in "kn-" and are cognates of the English words with the same meaning

Tags: etymology, noun, morphology

The title pretty much says it all.

- *Knopf* — *knob*
- *Knie* — *knee*

Are there more?

Comment: Viel Spaß beim Durchwühlen: http://wortsuche.com/starts-with-by-length/kn/

Comment: I am curious: Why this kind of special question?

Comment: @Ox6d64: "Why this question? Probably because it is a "curiousity."

Comment: @TomAu And tomorrow we ask for all words that begin in "pl", and the day after tomorrow ... No, seriously. I don't see any reason why that question is interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- knuckle – Knöchel (generally “ankle”, but colloquially this can be used in the same sense)

There are some other cognates whose meanings have diverged over time:

- knave – Knabe
- knight – Knecht
- knife – Kniff

Comment: Adding words "whose meanings have diverged over time" confuses the issue. For instance, Knecht means, servant, basically the OPPOSITE of knight. I can get from Knave, a "naughty" boy to Knabe. And I'm now confused about knife and Kniff http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/is-there-a-difference-between-messer-and-kniff

Comment: @TomAu: Merriam Webster: "a mounted man-at-arms serving a feudal superior [...] from Old English cniht man-at-arms, boy, servant". Not much divergent -- rather enlightening about the deeper meaning, exactly what etymology should do.

Answer (score 6):

Just one that I can spontaneously think of: *Knoten* — *knot*.

Answer (score 5):

Just another: *kneten* — *to knead*.

Answer (score -3):

- *Knolle* — *bulb/tuber*
- *knüllen* — *to crumple*

I don't believe it can be universally applied.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?