# Is there a difference between "Messer" and "Kniff?"

Tags: etymology, word-choice

The word I was taught for "knife" is "Messer".

But someone, who appears to be a native speaker, [answered a question](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4495/1224) to the effect that "Kniff" looked like its English counterpart "knife".

Certain other Germanic languages, such as Swedish, use "kniv".

So, was "Kniff" ever an older German word for "knife", at least in some dialects, that is no longer in common use?

Comment: I know Kniff as pinch and I did never associated it with knife before your post

Comment: @Emanuel: I double-checked, and the person listed "Kniff" under words that "have diverged over time." So maybe it's wrong to say it's "knife." But in that case, he didn't answer the question, and confused me. He also associates knight with Knecht, which I believe to be "servant," not knight.

Comment: @TomAu: You are right about Knecht. A "knight" would be "Ritter" in German.

Comment: @TomAu:  But the point is that knight and Knecht originate from the same word in some old form of German.

Comment: @Tara: +1, that's the point. Tom: It was the English _knight_ that used to be a lot closer to today's meaning of _Knecht_, see [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=knight) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight#Etymology).

Comment: There are various names for knive in the german dialects. Two of them I remember are "kniep" (Bergisches Land) and "kneipscher" or "kneip-chen" (Westerwald). These are names for the small knives in the kitchend for peeling potatos and stuff.
Not far away from "knive"

Comment: Also see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneip : "Kneip ist im Mittelhochdeutschen auch die Bezeichnung für Messer". I also knew the dialect word "Kneipsche" for a small knife.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed both words *"knife"* and *"Kniff"* sound very similar but their meaning is entirely different. For German we have this etymology:

> - **Kniff** *m.* das Kneifen, dadurch entstandene Falte in Papier oder Stoff, Mitte des 18. Jhs. zum Verb *kneifen* (s. d.) gebildet. Die Bedeutung *Kunstgriff, Trick, List* (ebenfalls 18. Jh., doch vgl. bereits gleichbed. mnd. *knēp*) leitet sich von der betrügerischen Kennzeichnung von Spielkarten durch Einkneifen her. – *kniffen* Vb. ‘in Falten legen, falzen’ (19. Jh.).<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Kniff&view=1)</sup>
> - **a)** die urspr. bed. ist offenbar diebischer 'kunstgriff', diebskniff (vgl. diebsgriff 2, 1095), nd. dûvenknêp (dûve gleich hd. deube, diebstahl), diebsgriff, heimtückischer streich Brem. wb. 1, 278, Stürenb. 43b. doch könnte kniff bestimmter vom betrügerischen kneifen, kneipen der würfel und karten entstanden sein (s. kneipen II, 1, k)...<sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK08966)</sup>

In short, the noun *"der Kniff"* was built from the verb *"kneifen"*. The original meaning desribed the fraudulent folding or marking of playing cards.

The etymology of the English *"knife"* is somewhat unclear:

> - **knife (n.)** late O.E. cnif, probably from O.N. knifr, from P.Gmc. *knibaz (cf. M.L.G. knif, M.Du. cnijf, Ger. kneif), of uncertain origin. To further confuse the etymology, there also are forms in -p-, e.g. Du. knijp, Ger. kneip. French canif "penknife" (mid-15c.) is borrowed from Middle English or Norse.<sup>[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=knife)</sup>

So there is some discussion for a possible common etymology of *"knife*" from German *"kneif"* but the relationship is not clear.

Comment: A "Kniff" has the characteristic of having s kind of edge, just like the blade of a knife. Could there be the connection or am I just guessing there?

Comment: Sounds like "knife," "Kniff," and "Kneifen" are all "sharp," and that's what they have in common.

Answer (score 4):

In Lower Franconia, around Aschaffenburg, there is the word *Kneipchen* used for small handy kitchen knives, so I'd say that *knife* doesn't correlate to *Kniff* but to *Kneip* / *Kneipchen*.

Comment: _Kneipchen_ is also used in Hessen.

Comment: I know *Kneipchen* as a small kitchen knife that you would use for peeling apples. In an old dictionary for Swabian, I find *Kneip* or *Kneiper* defined as a *Schustermesser* (shoemakers' knife) or *Rebmesser* (i.e., to cut wine grapes).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the etymology of "Messer."

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Messer#Etymology_1

It refers specifically to an eating utensil. Of course, the meaning has become more general over time.

Comment: Please don't give answers that only reference a link.

Answer (score -1):

Edited answer.

The Messer is a knife (a tool) the kniff is a trick to solve a tricky (German: "knifflig") problem (based on knowledge or experience). A Kniff has nothing in common with a knife.